# How to change Node's authored on date?

Tags: datetime, importing-exporting

What is the proper way to address and modify a node's authored on date? I created a slew of new nodes via a CSV import via the Feeds module. These nodes now have the date of 2013-07-11 as the authored on date as that's when I did the import. But each node refers to a previous date and I need the authored on date to reflect that.

I have a content type I've created that has a separate Date field where I choose the date. I'd like to eliminate that and just use the authored on date instead.

I'm trying to use VBO to run a custom PHP snippet to make this change but the examples I've found so far do not work.

```
$object->created = $object->field_date[0]['value'];
node_save($object);
```

This snippet when run through VBO returns errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: object in eval() (line 1 of /home/chriscor/public_html  /hi_tracker/sites/all/modules/contrib/views_bulk_operations/actions/script.action.inc(20) : eval()'d code).
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in eval() (line 1 of /home/chriscor/public_html/hi_tracker/sites/all/modules/contrib/views_bulk_operations/actions/script.action.inc(20) : eval()'d code).
>
> EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7693 of /home/chriscor/public_html/hi_tracker/includes/common.inc).

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the $object variable doesn't exist, or isn't in scope. Check the arguments your function receives for the proper node object.

Comment: Thanks Yuriy.  I'm not even writing a function though.  All I want to do is run some code in the custom PHP code section of VBO that updates the authored on date.  Is there perhaps a better way to do this?

Comment: Ah, right, that's why there's the eval business going on. Then it's the same issue as what I described, just in a different context. Try replacing $object with $node; if that still doesn't work, you'll need to refer to the VBO documentation to see what the correct object name is.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have probably figure this out by now but in Drupal 7 I had to change $object to $entity and it work - kind of...it is printing today's date in there and not copying the date from the `field_post_date` into created. Anyway this change will get rid of the error.

This video helped me along with this link:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vcuITAQ_Qu0
- https://www.drupal.org/node/2818169

This code worked...

```
$entity -> created = strtotime($entity->field_post_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']);
node_save($entity);
```